Запрет Android приложению на завершение
Может ли кто подсказать, как мне сделать так чтобы: приложение не могло завершаться, в том числе если пользователь смахнул его из App switcher (последние приложения). Нужно чтоб оно именно не завершалось, а при открытии его через тап по иконки продолжало работать в том же месте, с теме же данными.
Приложение уже написано, желательен способ который не требует многих перемен. Или мб возможно написать дополнительное приложение к нему, которое бы реализовало мою идею. К слову варианты где требуется root тоже рассматриваются. Выражение благодарности за любую полезную информацию.

Кажется, надо сервис делать, если нужна фоновая активность. Ну а уж при запуске в любом случае состояние восстанавливать руками.

Спачибо. Фоновая активность имеется. Представим что я его свернул, перешёл в другое приложение, спустя 5-10 минут возвращаюсь через вкладки или иконку, оно остается в прежнем состоянии. Проблема в том что на длинной дистанции это не работает, да и защиту от кнопки «закрыть все вкладки» тоже бы хотелось

ForegroundService остается работать после "смахивания".
